# How change namespace and prefix in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

My customer wants to a web service for integration. They send me the documentation and I created a WCF Service with methods. 
But there are namespaces and prefixs problem. I didn't find any solution and I didn't find any suggest. For example there is a different tag (

Customer will send request like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://ws.common.haciosman.com">
<soapenv:Header />
   <soap:Body>
      <ws:getSystemStatus/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Customer wants to response like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getSystemStatusResponse xmlns:ns="http://ws.common.haciosman.com">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:OutputMessage" xmlns:ax21="http://ws.common.haciosman.com/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax21:code>200</ax21:code>
            <ax21:description>Success</ax21:description>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:getSystemStatusResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Okay, **I created a service** but namespace and prefix not match. My service response like that:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <getSystemStatusResponse>
         <getSystemStatusResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFLocal.cls" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:code>200</a:code>
            <a:description>Success</a:description>
         </getSystemStatusResult>
      </getSystemStatusResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you see,  tags are different. What is wrong and how can I change prefix in WCF Service?

Thanks for your reply.